# Java matcher pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of strings: ab10sdj, ba1wqa, cd03asce, dfasc, etc. I'm looking to get the group of digits from the strings that start either with ab, or with ba.

So if a string starts with ab/ba, I need the group of digits right after them. If there a way for me to achieve this via a java matcher/regex?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Actually it is quite easy. Have you tried anything to solve this task? What problem stops you from finishing your code?

Comment: u answered your own question. regex is the way forward

Comment: `^(?:ab|ba)(\d+)` or `(?<=^(?:ab|ba))\d+`

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for posting this as an answer but my current reputation level doesn't allow me 'comment' ... yet :)

As apposed to simply giving an answer to a relatively simple problem (without insulting your intelligence), I can help with diagnosing a solution. Try thinking the problem through in your mind, step by step. That is:

1. How do you test for the first 2 characters in a string?
2. If the test to point 1 passes (IE, they are ab or ba), how do you then process the rest of the string to test for 'digits' only?
3. How do you stop processing the 'digits' when you reach a non-digit?
4. Once you have your ab/ba prefix, only extracted the 'digits' immediately following the test condition, how will you handle the digits extracted?
5. Before considering placing the digits in a primitive type, you may wish to consider how many digits one may expect?

All the best with your code!

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ab10sdj, ba1wqa, cd03asce, dfasc
    String s1 = "ab10sdj";
    String s2 = "ba1wqa";
    String s3 = "cd03asce";
    String s4 = "dfasc";
    String pattern = "^(ab|ba)(\\d+).*";
    System.out.println(s1.replaceAll(pattern, "$2")); // output 10
    System.out.println(s2.replaceAll(pattern, "$2")); // output 1
    System.out.println(s3.replaceAll(pattern, "$2")); // output cd03asce i.e, no change
    System.out.println(s4.replaceAll(pattern, "$2")); // output dfasc i.e, no change
}
```